# Python convert image array(20,20) to array(400)

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

Using Python 2.7 and Numpy.

I have a B/W image stored in array(20,20) and I would like to convert it to an array(400). How can this be done in Python if I have many images, that is array(x,20,20)?

Thanks a lot!

EDIT: Thanks a lot. I got the problem wrong at the beginning, thus I was not able to figure out this simple piece of code.

Comment: Reshape to `arr.reshape(-1,400)`?

Comment: @Leta A 20x20 array collapsed into a 1D array will give you 400 results. Multiplying the values will only change the color of each pixel.

Comment: Sorry, really stupid of me. I've got no idea how I got this wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I think `numpy.flatten()` is what you are looking for

```
>>> a = np.array([[1,2], [3,4]])
>>> a.flatten()
array([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> a.flatten('F')
array([1, 3, 2, 4])
```

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html

Comment: No. If I have an array(A,B), I need an array(A*B). What you wrote is an array(A+B).

The array for your example should read array([3, 4, 6, 8]).

Comment: @Leta That does not make much sense, given your question or basic ML-applications following which i assume here. In the latter case you surely don't want to change the pixel-values, only the outer dimension. **This answer** is okay. But one should understand that it will always be a copy (can be different from ravel shown in the other answer).

Comment: @Leta: That makes no sense.

Comment: Now I see how foolish I was. Sorry!

Comment: @Leta as mentioned above (by Divakar) numpy's reshape function is another option if you need more control of the shape.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`np.ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) to get a 1D view of the array if possible; otherwise a copy is returned.  See the linked documentation for the definition of 'if possible'.

```
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
print(a.ravel())
# [1 2 3 4 5 6]
```